# How to create my own online media player compatible with all browsers?

Tags: flash

I have being thinking to create a website for music uploading and downloading!
I have thought a lot and had been able to create it! But i'am stuck with this fear that windows media player would not be able to support with other browsers like SAFARI!
Can anyone have a better idea other than Windows Media Player please let me know!
One thing that script should be customizable with graphics and free!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of social networks (Last FM, MySpace, GrooveShark, etc.) with ability to listen there music use custom flash movie players. I suppose it's good point to look in direction of flash based player. And using flash give you ability to customize everything, *really* everything.